# How to make vector of pointers to items in another subvector?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, vector

I'm trying to make a vector that holds pointers to each of the first strings in a vector of vector of strings.  I'm going to be passing `first_words_in_subvecs` to the `\bin\sort` program to sort/print them.  I figured it's a waste of cpu time/space to make a new vector of actual strings, since I'm just going to be passing them anyway.  Am I right in thinking it will be faster to just make pointers to the strings I want to send?  And why doesn't this code work?  I don't get any warnings or errors, but it seg faults when I run it.

```
int print_sorted_subvectors(vector< vector<string> > &sorted_subsets_vec)
{   
    vector<string*>  first_words_in_subvecs;

    for(int i = 0; i < sorted_subsets_vec.size(); i++)
    {
        first_words_in_subvecs[i] = &sorted_subsets_vec[i][0];
    }
}
```

Comment: You are aware of [`std::sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), right?

Comment: well i am now!  that'll be easier...we were using the fork and bin\sort for another part of the assignment so I was going to use it again, but that'll be a lot easier...stupid pipes...so then I guess I will have to copy instead of point to.  But how would this be done?  I'm still curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably no need to store pointers to strings in a vector. The `std::string` class is pretty efficient, using techniques such as copy-on-write to avoid unnecessary copies of actual string data. You'll probably have no efficiency problem if `first_words_in_subvecs` is a regular `vector<string>` (and your code will be easier to understand and more reliable, too).

It's hard to say why your current code is segfaulting. Are you certain that every sub-vector of `sorted_subsets_vec` is nonempty?

Comment: that could be it.  is there a similar function that will go thru a vector and tell you which element is smallest?  I guess I really don't need to actually sort it.  just need to find the smallest element.  min_element works?

Comment: @FrederickCraine: Yup, [`std::min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) would do what you want. This returns an iterator, so check against `.end()` to see whether there were any elements at all (or check for `.empty()` first).